# Are men with dead or divorced wives before the first year still exempt

Tags: halacha, marriage, army-military-war, ki-teitzei, even-haezer

According to Deuteronomy 24:5 a man is exempt from public service for a year when he marries a wife. What does Halacha say in the case a man marries a woman and divorced her or she dies before that year, is he still exempt or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verse clearly states

> כִּֽי־יִקַּ֥ח אִישׁ֙ אִשָּׁ֣ה חֲדָשָׁ֔ה לֹ֤א יֵצֵא֙ בַּצָּבָ֔א וְלֹא־יַעֲבֹ֥ר עָלָ֖יו לְכׇל־דָּבָ֑ר נָקִ֞י יִהְיֶ֤ה לְבֵיתוֹ֙ שָׁנָ֣ה אֶחָ֔ת **וְשִׂמַּ֖ח אֶת־אִשְׁתּ֥וֹ אֲשֶׁר־לָקָֽח**׃‏

I.e. that he is to remain homebound to **make his wife happy**. If he's not married to her anymore, then he would lose his exemption.

Rashi also hints to this by saying that it's *for the purpose of his wife*:

> נקי יהיה לביתו. פירש"י בשביל ביתו